# Calculate sum of int input numbers only stop with non-numerical input

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ with *"C++ Primer"*, an example of "calculating the sum of input values" is below:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>

    int main()

    {

        int sum = 0, value = 0;

        // read until end-of-file, calculating a running total of all values read

        while (std::cin >> value)

            sum += value; // equivalent to sum = sum + value

        std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Then when I type "3 4 5 6 <kbd>enter</kbd>", it does not end and export result as the book shows. Only when I type "3 4 5 6 f <kbd>enter</kbd>" it ends and exports result, 'f' could be any other non-numerical character.

**Update**

There is some explanation in the book but written too far after the code, suffered.

Comment: `while (std::cin >> value)` will keep reading as long as those reads are successful. Since `value` is an `int`, it will keep reading until you enter something that doesn't make sense for an `int`.

Comment: It does not export `f`. When `f` is encountered the stream state is set do `.fail()` (e.g. `failbit` is set) and character extraction ceases at that point. `f` is left unread in `stdin` and simply remains on the input line due to the failure. You should declare a `std::string input;` and then use `getline (std::cin, input) ` to read the input checking if `input` is empty to know when **[Enter]** alone was pressed. Otherwise create a `std::stringstream` from the line where you could then loop reading integers from the stringstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, if you want to end collection of number input when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty line, then you want to read input into a `std::string` using `getline()` and then parse the integer values from the string using `std::stringstream` which will allow you to handle multiple integers entered on the same line, or one integer per line (or in any combination). See [std::basic_stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

You can modify your code as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main (void) {
    
    std::string input{};
    int sum = 0;
    
    while (getline (std::cin, input)) {           // read input with getline
        int value;
        if (input.length() == 0)                  // if input empty, done reading
            break;
        std::stringstream ss (input);             // create stringstream from input
        while (ss >> value)                       // loop reading ints from stringstream
            sum += value;                         // add to sum
    }
    
    std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << '\n';
}
```

(**note:** no matter if you enter a non-integer value, the stream state is unaffected. The non-integer will cause reading from the stringstream to stop when the non-integer is encountered (you can add code to handle the error, that is left to you), but it will not affect your next input.)

If input of only a single line of numbers is desired, and you want the sum computed when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you can simply change the `while()` to an `if()`, e.g.

```
    if (getline (std::cin, input)) {              // read input with getline
```

Then input will stop the first time <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed. That was a bit unclear, thank you [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706785/peter).

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getline_ss_sum
1 2 3

Sum is: 6
```

Or entering one number per line:

```
$ ./bin/getline_ss_sum
1
2
3

Sum is: 6
```

In each case input is complete when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty line.

Comment: The question is a little ambiguous, but I suspect the OP wants reading to stop the first time the user hits "Enter" (i.e. without the user having to enter an empty line).   That can be done by changing the outer `while` in your code to an `if`.   With that change, your first example will still work as you describe but the second example will stop after entering `1`  (without reading or summing up the lines with `2` or `3`).

Comment: Good point. If only a single line of number is wanted, then the `while (getline (...))` can be replaced with `if (getline (...))`.